# Is there a TCP protocol violation causing "TCP connection lost" in these packets?

Tags: networking, tcp

I have narrowed down a failure in communications to the following exchange. I can see the TCP establishment SYN, SYN/ACK, and ACK packets starting at packet #74. 22ms later, the connection is reported lost (very near the PSH packet #77) and I can't understand why. Is it ACKing the wrong SEQ? Comms are over a PLC link if it matters. The .6232 address belongs to my side of the link.

Many thanks in advance.

The evidence:

An EVSE communications controller (whose code I am not privileged to see) reports the following sequence of events:

```
[16/11/23_13:38:37:606] [Message] Sdp request successfully received and checked!
[16/11/23_13:38:37:797] [Message] TCP connection established ...
[16/11/23_13:38:37:801] [Message] Expected next Request: SupportedAppProtocol
[16/11/23_13:38:37:819] [Message] TCP connection lost ...
```

with these packets tcpdump'ed from the same EVSE's network:

```
#71 13:38:37.603416 IP6 fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf > ff02::1:ff62:6232: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232, length 32
    0x0000:  3333 ff62 6232 0001 8705 2cbf 86dd 6000  33.bb2....,...`.
    0x0010:  0000 0020 3aff fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ....:...........
    0x0020:  87ff fe05 2cbf ff02 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....,...........
    0x0030:  0001 ff62 6232 8700 4ce8 0000 0000 fe80  ...bb2..L.......
    0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0201 01ff fe62 6232 0101  ...........bb2..
    0x0050:  0001 8705 2cbf                           ....,.
#72 13:38:37.620216 IP6 fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232 > fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232, length 32
    0x0000:  0001 8705 2cbf 0001 0162 6232 86dd 6000  ....,....bb2..`.
    0x0010:  0000 0020 3aff fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ....:...........
    0x0020:  01ff fe62 6232 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ...bb2..........
    0x0030:  87ff fe05 2cbf 8800 389b 6000 0000 fe80  ....,...8.`.....
    0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0201 01ff fe62 6232 0201  ...........bb2..
    0x0050:  0001 0162 6232                           ...bb2
#73 13:38:37.620431 IP6 fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf.15118 > fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232.56978: UDP, length 28
    0x0000:  0001 0162 6232 0001 8705 2cbf 86dd 6000  ...bb2....,...`.
    0x0010:  0000 0024 1140 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ...$.@..........
    0x0020:  87ff fe05 2cbf fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ....,...........
    0x0030:  01ff fe62 6232 3b0e de92 0024 ac61 01fe  ...bb2;....$.a..
    0x0040:  9001 0000 0014 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ................
    0x0050:  87ff fe05 2cbf cdec 1000                 ....,.....
#74 13:38:37.784028 IP6 fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232.56056 > fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf.52716: Flags [S], seq 7266836, win 3107, options [mss 1440], length 0
    0x0000:  0001 8705 2cbf 0001 0162 6232 86dd 6000  ....,....bb2..`.
    0x0010:  0000 0018 06ff fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ................
    0x0020:  01ff fe62 6232 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ...bb2..........
    0x0030:  87ff fe05 2cbf daf8 cdec 006e e214 0000  ....,......n....
    0x0040:  0000 6002 0c23 ea52 0000 0204 05a0       ..`..#.R......
#75 13:38:37.784415 IP6 fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf.52716 > fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232.56056: Flags [S.], seq 206804358, ack 7266837, win 14400, options [mss 1440], length 0
    0x0000:  0001 0162 6232 0001 8705 2cbf 86dd 6000  ...bb2....,...`.
    0x0010:  0000 0018 0640 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  .....@..........
    0x0020:  87ff fe05 2cbf fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ....,...........
    0x0030:  01ff fe62 6232 cdec daf8 0c53 9586 006e  ...bb2.....S...n
    0x0040:  e215 6012 3840 1c4b 0000 0204 05a0       ..`.8@.K......
#76 13:38:37.794237 IP6 fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232.56056 > fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf.52716: Flags [.], ack 1, win 3107, length 0
    0x0000:  0001 8705 2cbf 0001 0162 6232 86dd 6000  ....,....bb2..`.
    0x0010:  0000 0014 06ff fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ................
    0x0020:  01ff fe62 6232 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ...bb2..........
    0x0030:  87ff fe05 2cbf daf8 cdec 006e e215 0c53  ....,......n...S
    0x0040:  9587 5010 0c23 6011 0000                 ..P..#`...
#77 13:38:37.810215 IP6 fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232.56056 > fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf.52716: Flags [P.], seq 1:18, ack 1, win 3107, length 17
    0x0000:  0001 8705 2cbf 0001 0162 6232 86dd 6000  ....,....bb2..`.
    0x0010:  0000 0025 06ff fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ...%............
    0x0020:  01ff fe62 6232 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ...bb2..........
    0x0030:  87ff fe05 2cbf daf8 cdec 006e e215 0c53  ....,......n...S
    0x0040:  9587 5018 0c23 ebbc 0000 01fe 8001 0000  ..P..#..........
    0x0050:  0009 809a 0010 1108 4080 20              ........@..
#78 13:38:37.810533 IP6 fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf.52716 > fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232.56056: Flags [.], ack 18, win 14400, length 0
    0x0000:  0001 0162 6232 0001 8705 2cbf 86dd 6000  ...bb2....,...`.
    0x0010:  0000 0014 0640 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  .....@..........
    0x0020:  87ff fe05 2cbf fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ....,...........
    0x0030:  01ff fe62 6232 cdec daf8 0c53 9587 006e  ...bb2.....S...n
    0x0040:  e226 5010 3840 33e3 0000                 .&P.8@3...
#79 13:38:37.814004 IP6 fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232.56056 > fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf.52716: Flags [.], ack 1, win 3107, length 0
    0x0000:  0001 8705 2cbf 0001 0162 6232 86dd 6000  ....,....bb2..`.
    0x0010:  0000 0014 06ff fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ................
    0x0020:  01ff fe62 6232 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ...bb2..........
    0x0030:  87ff fe05 2cbf daf8 cdec 006e e215 0c53  ....,......n...S
    0x0040:  9587 5010 0c23 6011 0000                 ..P..#`...
#80 13:38:37.814310 IP6 fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf.52716 > fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232.56056: Flags [.], ack 18, win 14400, length 0
    0x0000:  0001 0162 6232 0001 8705 2cbf 86dd 6000  ...bb2....,...`.
    0x0010:  0000 0014 0640 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  .....@..........
    0x0020:  87ff fe05 2cbf fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ....,...........
    0x0030:  01ff fe62 6232 cdec daf8 0c53 9587 006e  ...bb2.....S...n
    0x0040:  e226 5010 3840 33e3 0000                 .&P.8@3...
#81 13:38:37.817695 IP6 fe80::201:87ff:fe05:2cbf.52716 > fe80::201:1ff:fe62:6232.56056: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 18, win 14400, length 0
    0x0000:  0001 0162 6232 0001 8705 2cbf 86dd 6000  ...bb2....,...`.
    0x0010:  0000 0014 0640 fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  .....@..........
    0x0020:  87ff fe05 2cbf fe80 0000 0000 0000 0201  ....,...........
    0x0030:  01ff fe62 6232 cdec daf8 0c53 9587 006e  ...bb2.....S...n
    0x0040:  e226 5011 3840 33e2 0000                 .&P.8@3...
```

Comment: The final one is a FIN, which means the sender has closed the connection, or at least shut it down for output.

Comment: Packets #74 through #76 show the TCP connection being established; packet #81 shows EVSE reporting the closure to my device. Someone gets unhappy somewhere in packets #77 through #80, though I don't see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason for the communications termination was that the network management key on the powerline communications controller was reset and the link dropped. Nothing to do with the comms, which is why they were not appearing in the Wireshark log.

The one packet that was sent was a CableCheck.REQ which the EVSE was not prepared for. (The correct packet should have been the SupportedAppProtocol.REQ as indicated by the EVSE log.)